# FileHelpers add extra column dynamically

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am reading CSV using FileHelpers and there are 3 columns in CSV. I am able to read them as I have class file which has these 3 properties. I need one more dynamic column to be added. 
Like I need to add date to each row. But if I add date property within a class then it gives error saying no field/column available
If I have hidden field attribute to date then the date is eliminated.

Eg.
I have CSV 
Name, address, phone

I need result as
Name Address phone todaysdate

Class I am having

```
 [DelimitedRecord (",")]
 Public class csvrecords
 {
         [FieldOptional]
         Public string _name;
         Public string name
         {
                Get {return _name;}
                Set {_name = value;}
          }

         [FieldOptional]
         Public string _address;
         Public string address
         {
                Get {return _address;}
                Set {_name = address;}
          }


          [FieldOptional]
          Public string _phone;
          Public string phone
         {
                Get {return _phone;}
                Set {_phone = value;}
           }
   }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you get any solution ?